# Why should I need to add jQueryMobile Script only after all other scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

> If I add any other scripts after JQM script then my page doesn't work properly.
>          Also according to Jqm docs I must include jQM script at the end of other scripts.
>         
>  **What's the reason behind it ?**
>   
>  Thanks

Comment: what script are you loading into jqm template?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not always the case, but there are some situations when this is necessary. Any plugin than can cause a change to the page content loaded into the DOM must be initialized before jQuery Mobile. Best example is jQuery UI.

To understand this you need to understand how jQuery Mobile works. When jQM initialize it load's everything into the DOM. Even then process is not over because when content is loaded then jQM starts a markup enhancement process (custom widget styling). This process should not be tempered with because it could cause problems with widgets initialization.

One more thing, if jQuery Mobile detects something else is messing with a DOM content during the page initialization it will stop the process and ajax page loader will be shown.